# How to get one string using two different condition on it using regex in asp.net

Tags: regex, asp.net-4.0

I have a string in which I have to find PNR number. To get PNR number I have to check two condition:

1. First in Passenger should be more than one.
2. Second String contain ITINERARY REBOOKED.

If both condition and met then extract only the PNR number from the string otherwise return nothing.

Examples of input strings :

```
 string First=@"RT29WHVE

 RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            WS/SU   6MAY13/0503Z   29WHVE // This is PNR number                
  NYC1S21DD/9525GY/6MAY13                                                         
 1.KHOON/FRANCIS   2.MEH/SAY   3.MEH/PRAY   4.MEH/MAW      //Passenger more than one                    
 5.REH/LAW   6.REH/PAE   7.REH/DO   8.REH/LEE   9.REH/HEH                      
 10  US 152 T 12MAY 7 GEGPHX HK9   300P 534P 12MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 11  US 184 T 12MAY 7 PHXLAS HK9   815P 923P 12MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 12  US 392 K 13MAY 1 LASCLT HK9   115A 827A 13MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 13  US4286 K 13MAY 1 CLTFAY HK9   955A1050A 13MAY  E  US/A4PRHM                
 OPERATED BY SUBSIDIARY/FRANCHISE                                           
 14 MIS 1A HK9 NYC 11JAN-THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS                            
 15 AP NYC9103161516                                                            
 16 APE FRANCISKHON@GMAIL.COM                                                   
 17 TK OK06MAY/NYC1S21DD//ETUS                                                  
 18 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////09NOV83/M//KHOON/FRANCIS/P1                             
 19 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////01JAN92/M//MEH/SAY/P2                                   
 20 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////01JAN62/M//MEH/PRAY/P3                                  
 21 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////01JAN96/M//MEH/MAW/P4                                   
 22 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////15APR89/M//REH/LAW/P5                                   
 23 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////11NOV97/M//REH/PAE/P6                                   
 24 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////01JAN59/M//REH/DO/P7                                    
 25 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////05OCT88/M//REH/LEE/P8  
)>SP1                                                               
RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            WS/SU   6MAY13/0503Z   XXXXXX                
 1.KHOON/FRANCIS                                                              
 2  US 152 T 12MAY 7 GEGPHX HK1   300P 534P 12MAY  E  US/A4PRHM               
 3  US 184 T 12MAY 7 PHXLAS HK1   815P 923P 12MAY  E  US/A4PRHM               
 4  US 392 K 13MAY 1 LASCLT HK1   115A 827A 13MAY  E  US/A4PRHM               
 5  US4286 K 13MAY 1 CLTFAY HK1   955A1050A 13MAY  E  US/A4PRHM               
 OPERATED BY SUBSIDIARY/FRANCHISE                                          
 6 MIS 1A HK1 NYC 11JAN-THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS                           
 7 AP NYC9103161516                                                           
 8 APE FRANCISKHON@GMAIL.COM                                                  
 9 TK OK06MAY/NYC1S21DD//ETUS                                                 
10 SSR DOCS US HK1 ////09NOV83/M//KHOON/FRANCIS                               
11 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752856                                               
12 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752857                                               
13 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752858                                               
14 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752859                                               
15 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752860                                               
16 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752861                                               
17 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752862                                               
18 OSI US TKT NO 037-7244752863     
                                                          FXR                                                                                                                                 
01 KHOON/FRANC*                                                                
 ITINERARY REBOOKED         //It contain ITINERATY REBOOKED so fetch that PNR  numebr                                                    
 LAST TKT DTE 06MAY13 - SEE ADV PURCHASE                                        
 ------------------------------------------------------------                   
     AL FLGT  BK   DATE  TIME  FARE BASIS      NVB  NVA   BG                   
  GEG                                                                           
 XPHX US   152 K *  12MAY 1500  KXA0NL6P        12MAY12MAY 0P                   
  LAS US   184 K *  12MAY 2015  KXA0NL6P        12MAY12MAY 0P                   
 XCLT US   392 K    13MAY 0115  KXA7NJ6         13MAY13MAY 0P                   
 FAY US  4286 K    13MAY 0955  KXA7NJ6         13MAY13MAY 0P                   

  USD   290.24      12MAY13GEG US X/PHX US LAS144.19KXA0NL6P                     
              US X/CLT US FAY146.05KXA7NJ6 USD290.24END                    
  USD    21.76US    ZP GEG3.90PHX3.90LAS3.90CLT3.90XT USD                        
  USD     5.00AY    15.60ZP USD 9.00XF GEG4.50PHX4.50                            
  USD    24.60XT                                                                 
  USD   341.60                                                                   
  BG CXR: US                                                                     
  PRICED WITH VALIDATING CARRIER US - REPRICE IF DIFFERENT VC                    
>                                                 PAGE  2/ 3                   
>";

     string Second=@"rt298BFB
 --- TST RLR MSC ---                                                            
   RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            UA/RM   6MAY13/0452Z   298BFB // This is PNR   number               
 NYC1S21DD/9999WS/6MAY13                                                        
 1.BELIEU/KENNETH E(ADT)   2.BELIEU/RUTH J(ADT)                               
 3  UA 646 Q 22JUN 6*PDXORD HK2   603A1150A 22JUN  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 4  UA1735 Q 22JUN 6*ORDBWI HK2   115P 409P 22JUN  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 5  UA 209 S 01JUL 1*BWIIAH HK2   545A 800A 01JUL  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 6  UA 258 S 01JUL 1*IAHPDX HK2   856A1120A 01JUL  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
 7 MIS 1A HK2 NYC 11JAN-THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS                           
 8 MCO XD ARC 06MAY/USD 44.00/*SERVICE FEE/P1                                 
 9 AP NYC5093952712                                                           
 10 API CHEAPOAIR, 213 WEST 35TH STREET, SUITE 1201, NEW YORK,                 
   NY 10001                                                                
 11 TK OK06MAY/NYC1S21DD//ETUA                                                 
 12 SSR SEAT UA KK2 PDXORD/36AN,P1/36BN,P2/RB/S3                               
 13 SSR SEAT UA KK2 ORDBWI/31FN,P1/31EN,P2/RB/S4                               
)>sp1
 --- TST RLR MSC ---                                                            
 -ASSOCIATE PNR-                                                                
 RP/NYC1S21DD/NYC1S21DD            UA/RM   6MAY13/0452Z   XXXXXX                
  1.BELIEU/KENNETH E(ADT)                                                      
  2  UA 646 Q 22JUN 6*PDXORD HK1   603A1150A 22JUN  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
  3  UA1735 Q 22JUN 6*ORDBWI HK1   115P 409P 22JUN  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
  4  UA 209 S 01JUL 1*BWIIAH HK1   545A 800A 01JUL  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
  5  UA 258 S 01JUL 1*IAHPDX HK1   856A1120A 01JUL  E  UA/GW0LVJ               
  6 MIS 1A HK1 NYC 11JAN-THANK YOU FOR YOUR BUSINESS                           
  7 MCO XD ARC 06MAY/USD 44.00/*SERVICE FEE                                    
  8 AP NYC5093952712                                                           
  9 API CHEAPOAIR, 213 WEST 35TH STREET, SUITE 1201, NEW YORK,                 
   NY 10001                                                                
  10 TK OK06MAY/NYC1S21DD//ETUA                                                 
  11 SSR SEAT UA KK1 PDXORD/36AN,P1/RB/S2                                             
   )>FXR
    FXR                                                                              
 01 BELIEU/KENNE*                                                               
  NO REBOOKING REQUIRED FOR LOWEST AVAILABLE FARE //it contain no booking so dont want that PNR number                               
 LAST TKT DTE 07MAY13 - SEE ADV PURCHASE                                        
 ------------------------------------------------------------                   
      AL FLGT  BK   DATE  TIME  FARE BASIS      NVB  NVA   BG                   
PDX                                                                           
XCHI UA   646 Q    22JUN 0603  QA7KN           22JUN22JUN 0P                   
BWI UA  1735 Q    22JUN 1315  QA7KN           22JUN22JUN 0P                   
XHOU UA   209 S    01JUL 0545  SA7KN           01JUL01JUL 0P                   
PDX UA   258 S    01JUL 0856  SA7KN           01JUL01JUL 0P                   

USD   547.91      22JUN13PDX UA X/CHI UA BWI323.72QA7KN UA                     
              X/HOU UA PDX224.19SA7KN USD547.91END                         
USD    41.09US    ZP PDX3.90ORD3.90BWI3.90IAH3.90XT USD                        
USD    10.00AY    15.60ZP USD 16.50XF PDX4.50ORD4.50BWI4.50                    
USD    32.10XT    IAH3.00                                                      
USD   631.10                                                                   
BG CXR: UA                                                                     
PRICED WITH VALIDATING CARRIER UA - REPRICE IF DIFFERENT VC>";
```

The regex I am using currently is `(\s[A-Z0-9]{6}\s{2})(?=(.*ITINERARY.REBOOKED.?))`
it will give me PNR number which contain ITINERARY REBOOKED but I want first condition too.

Comment: It is not clear in the example what part of the data is this PMR number: please specify that separately in the question because there are lots of things that are numbers (and identifiers that might be called "numbers") in the examples.

Comment: in second line of code you will find PNR and in 4th line of code you will find passenger name and number

Comment: Sorry, don't understand, or are you say the *whole fourth line* is the PNR? (And are blank lines significant?). Amitesh: you need to follow the principle: make the question *easy* to answer.

Comment: Sry Richard i will explain here   This is my PNR number 29WHVE these are my passenger name and number 1.KHOON/FRANCIS   2.MEH/SAY   3.MEH/PRAY   4.MEH/MAW i want to fetch that PNR number using 2 condition 1st i want to check whether string contain ITINERARY REBOOKED and second the passenger should be more than 2 it string has more than two pax and ITINERARY REBOOKED then only fetch that PNR number using regex i hope now i am clear

Comment: @Richard can i create two different regex for it and call them in the same function

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on the question start to explain: there is a lot of ambiguity here: if a PNR is a 6 character alphanumeric string then there are many many things that can match in the input strings, so more detailed criteria about the PNR format *and* where it appears really need to be applied.

Assuming (based on the comments and a few guesses) the criteria can be specified more completely as:

- PNR is a six character upper case alphanumeric code.
- It appears at the end of the third line of the input

  - The comment says forth, but it is quite clearly the third in the example.
  - The text starting `//` has been added by the questioner but isn't actually part of the input.

The string should only be processed if it contains the literal text `ITINERARY REBOOKED`.

Thus no regex is needed:

```
bool TryGetPnr(string input, out string pnr) {
  pnr = String.Empty;

  if (input.IndexOf("ITINERARY REBOOKED", StringComparison.Ordinal) == -1) {
    return false;
  }

  // Get the 3rd line (index 2) without building too much of a temporary array
  // This assumes \r\n line endings.
  var line3 = input.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, 4, StringSplitOptions.None)[2];

  pnr = line3.Substring(line3.Length - 6);
  return true;
}
```

***BUT*** you need to start by carefully specifying exactly what you want to ensure you correctly extract only what you want. Currently the question's format specification vague at best.

Comment: The thing is that it only one string i have to check that regex for almost 15 strings

Comment: @amitesh So call that function in a loop: keep things simple for the core problem and then compose the overall solution from such building blocks. (You're expected to do a some work—including debugging—here.)